# Customize the ListView in a Fragment-based Master-Detail Flow?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, master-detail

I found the template that ADT generates for a Master/Detail Flow Activity to be rather obtuse, and I don't like the fact that the ListView is not declared in a layout file which forces me to work with it programatically.  For example, instead of just setting `android:background` on the ListView in a layout file, I'm forced to find the ListView via findViewById in the fragment's `onCreateView(...)` method, then call `setBackground(...)`.  For maintainability and general readability, I'd like to do the same thing via a layout file.

Instead, I'm trying to inflate a custom layout in the `onCreateView` method of the "master" fragment:

```
public class InboxFragment extends ListFragment {

public InboxFragment() {}

private ListView listView = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    listView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_fragment_layout, 
            null);
    return listView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // the following doesn't work
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(), 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, 
            android.R.id.text1, 
            DummyContent.ITEMS));
    // nor does this
    //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(), 
    //      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, 
    //      android.R.id.text1, 
    //      DummyContent.ITEMS));
}

}
```

However, calling `setListAdapter` (or even `setAdapter`) doesn't seem to do anything, even though I've given the ListView an id of `android:id="@id/android:list"` in `R.layout.inbox_fragment_layout`:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#D3D3D3" />
```

My "master" activity just calls a fragment layout:

```
public class InboxActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inbox_phone_layout);
    }

}
```

inbox_phone_layout.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentPhoneInbox"
    android:name="com.justin.inbox.InboxFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Instead, I'm greeted with a blank page and it doesn't look like the ListView is loaded at all.  What am I doing wrong, here? [Sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/justingarrick/fragmented-master-detail).

Comment: Why does your fragment have a width of 0dp and a weight of 1? Weights are only valid within a LinearLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your issue by changing `inbox_phone_layout.xml` to the following:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentPhoneInbox"
    android:name="com.justin.inbox.InboxFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue.  Copy/paste fail, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for ur help, My problem is when clicking the list item, detail activity is not opening.. What's wrong

Comment: It sounds like that question would be better answered by starting a new question and fully describing your issue and providing the relevant code snippets.